# HTML+JS Расчеты в динамической таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Таблица, в которую вводятся данные содержит ячейки - цена, количество. При вводе данных стоимость должна считаться автоматически. В этой таблице должны быть функции удаления и добавления строк. Сделано добавление и удаление строк.
Проблема в том, что у меня считается стоимость только в первой строке, а в остальных стоимость не считается...

```js
var DynamicTable = (function(GLOB) {
  var RID = 0;
  return function(tBody) {
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
      return new arguments.callee.apply(arguments);
    }
    tBody.onclick = function(e) {
      var evt = e || GLOB.event,
        trg = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
      if (trg.className && trg.className.indexOf("add") !== -1) {
        _addRow(trg.parentNode.parentNode, tBody);
      } else if (trg.className && trg.className.indexOf("del") !== -1) {
        tBody.rows.length > 1 && _delRow(trg.parentNode.parentNode, tBody);
      }
    };
    var _rowTpl = tBody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
    var _correctNames = function(row) {
      var elements = row.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
        if (elements.item(i).name) {
          if (elements.item(i).type &&
            elements.item(i).type === "text" &&
            elements.item(i).className &&
            elements.item(i).className.indexOf("glob") !== -1) {
            elements.item(i).value = RID;
          } else {
            elements.item(i).name = RID + "[" + elements.item(i).name + "]";
          }
        }
      }
      RID++;
      return row;
    };
    var _addRow = function(before, tBody) {
      var newNode = _correctNames(_rowTpl.cloneNode(true));
      tBody.insertBefore(newNode, before.nextSibling);
    };
    var _delRow = function(row, tBody) {
      tBody.removeChild(row);
    };
    _correctNames(tBody.rows[0]);
  };
})(this);


var tbls = document.getElementById("dynamic");
for (var r = 0; r < tbls.rows.length; r++) {
  // последовательнный перебор всех рядов в каждой таблице
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    array = ['load', 'keyup'],
    i = array.length;
  while (i--) {
    window['on' + array[i]] = function() {
      function $(i) {
        return ~~input[i].value;
      }
      input[3].value = $(1) * $(2);
      var vvv = $(1) * $(2);
      document.getElementById('sum').value = $(3).toFixed(2);

      var thisRow = tbls.rows;
      thisRow.cells[3] = thisRow.cells[1] * thisRow.cells[2];
      alert("ghj");
    };
  }
};

new DynamicTable(document.getElementById("dynamic"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TASK 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Таблица учета покупок.</h1>
  
  <form name="calc" class="calc">
    <table width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Товар</th>
          <th scope="col">Цена, руб.</th>
          <th scope="col">Количество</th>
          <th scope="col">Стоимость, руб.</th>
          <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="dynamic">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
               <input type="text" name="text" value="Наименование">
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
               <input type="number" value="0.00" required pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" >
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
               <input type="number" value="0.000" required pattern="\d+(\.\d{3})?">
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="number" id="sum" required pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"  >
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
            <button type="button" class="del">-</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var DynamicTable = (function(GLOB) {
  var RID = 0;
  return function(tBody) {
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
      return new arguments.callee.apply(arguments);
    }
    tBody.onclick = function(e) {
      var evt = e || GLOB.event,
        trg = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
      if (trg.className && trg.className.indexOf("add") !== -1) {
        _addRow(trg.parentNode.parentNode, tBody);
      } else if (trg.className && trg.className.indexOf("del") !== -1) {
        tBody.rows.length > 1 && _delRow(trg.parentNode.parentNode, tBody);
      }
    };
    var _rowTpl = tBody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
    var _correctNames = function(row) {
      var elements = row.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
        if (elements.item(i).name) {
          if (elements.item(i).type &&
            elements.item(i).type === "text" &&
            elements.item(i).className &&
            elements.item(i).className.indexOf("glob") !== -1) {
            elements.item(i).value = RID;
          } else {
            elements.item(i).name = RID + "[" + elements.item(i).name + "]";
          }
        }
      }
      RID++;
      return row;
    };
    var _addRow = function(before, tBody) {
      var newNode = _correctNames(_rowTpl.cloneNode(true));
      tBody.insertBefore(newNode, before.nextSibling);
    };
    var _delRow = function(row, tBody) {
      tBody.removeChild(row);
    };
    _correctNames(tBody.rows[0]);
  };
})(this);

/* ДОБАВЛЕНО */
window.onkeyup = function() {
  for (var r = 0; r < document.getElementById("dynamic").rows.length; r++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[r * 4 + 3].value = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[r * 4 + 1].value * document.getElementsByTagName('input')[r * 4 + 2].value;
  }

};

new DynamicTable(document.getElementById("dynamic"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TASK 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Таблица учета покупок.</h1>
  
  <form name="calc" class="calc">
    <table width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Товар</th>
          <th scope="col">Цена, руб.</th>
          <th scope="col">Количество</th>
          <th scope="col">Стоимость, руб.</th>
          <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="dynamic">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
                   <input type="text" name="text" value="Наименование">
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="number" value="0.00" required pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" >
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
               <input type="number" value="0.000" required pattern="\d+(\.\d{3})?">
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
             <input type="number" id="sum" required pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"  >
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
            <button type="button" class="del">-</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alex, спасибо большое! Все работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Добрый день! Скажите, а как после таблицы добавить сумму по колонке sum?

Comment: @Madam_X например вот так https://jsfiddle.net/dnL68Luo/

Comment: Alex , спасибо!